# MSBuild error using Microsoft Azure Logic Apps Enterprise Integration Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, biztalk, azure-sdk, biztalk-mapper

I have a solution set up consisting of multiple BizTalk btproj projects.

I also have the [Microsoft Azure Logic Apps Enterprise Integration Tools for Visual Studio 2015 2.0 installed](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53016).

When I build the solution using Visual Studio 2015, it succeeds. If I do so using MSBuild, I run into the following errors:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Azure Integration
>   SDK\IntegrationCommon.targets(29,5): error MSB4018: The
>   "MapperCompiler" task failed unexpectedly.
>   [C:\Users\User01\Documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SampleProject\Transform\myTransform.btproj]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Azure Integration
>   SDK\IntegrationCommon.targets(29,5): error MSB4018:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Integration.DesignTools.Studio.Extensibility,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   [C:\Users\User01\Documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SampleProject\Transform\myTransform.btproj]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Azure Integration
>   SDK\IntegrationCommon.targets(29,5): error MSB4018: File name:
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Integration.DesignTools.Studio.Extensibility,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   [C:\Users\User01\Documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SampleProject\Transform\myTransform.btproj]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Azure Integration
>   SDK\IntegrationCommon.targets(29,5): error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Integration.DesignTools.BizTalkProject.BuildTasks.MapperCompiler.Execute()
>   [C:\Users\User01\Documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SampleProject\Transform\myTransform.btproj]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Azure Integration
>   SDK\IntegrationCommon.targets(29,5): error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   [C:\Users\User01\Documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SampleProject\Transform\myTransform.btproj]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Azure Integration
>   SDK\IntegrationCommon.targets(29,5): error MSB4018:    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
>   [C:\Users\User01\Documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SampleProject\Transform\myTransform.btproj]

The MSBuild command I'm running is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin> ./MSBuild.exe $pathToProjectSln /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /target:Build /target:Clean
```

MapperCompiler is defined in the following file:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Azure Integration
>   SDK\IntegrationCommon.targets

as

```
<Target Name="GenerateXslt">
    <MapperCompiler MapItems="@(Map)"
                    SchemaItems="@(Schema)"
                    ProjectReferences="@(ReferencePath)"
                    WarningLevel="$(WarningLevel)"
                    RootNamespace="$(RootNamespace)"
                    EnableUnitTesting="false"
                    OutputDir ="$(OutputPath)"
                    >
    </MapperCompiler>
  </Target>
```

It looks like the SDK DLLs aren't being picked up. These are stored in the GAC but aren't explicitly referenced by the projects within the VS solution. Even if I add them as dependencies within each individual project, I still run into the same errors.

Would appreciate any help with this - thank you!

Comment: You can try to create a empty wiztalk project without using `Microsoft Azure Logic Apps Enterprise Integration Tools` and then use MSBuild to test whether it is the error of MSBuild or `Microsoft Azure Logic Apps Enterprise Integration Tools` and feel free to let us know.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Thanks Perry. I haven't tried with a blank BizTalk project but like you I strongly suspect that the issue is because of the `Microsoft Azure Integration Tools`. If I comment out the `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\Azure Integration SDK\IntegrationTasks.targets" />'` line in the `.btproj` files, I get past this error but am confronted with another: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2482,7): error MSB4057: The target "CreateManifestResourceNames" does not exist in the project.`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, but I don't understand what is the problem, because with VisualStudio build, instead with command prompt doesn't work.

In my case I uses the "Integration account project", I think that Biztalk Project needs the Biztalk installation.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while building a DevOps Pipeline, using a custom self-hosted build machine.
In my case the DLLs where not registered in the GAC.
From a VS2015 Developer Command Prompt, I launched GACUTIL for the following 5 file, and now is working without problems with MSBUILD.

Hope this helps

```
gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Integration SDK\IntegrationProjectExtnDir\Microsoft.Azure.Integration.DesignTools.Studio.Extensibility.dll" /f
gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Integration SDK\IntegrationProjectExtnDir\Microsoft.Azure.Integration.DesignTools.Mapper.Compiler.dll" /f
gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Integration SDK\IntegrationProjectExtnDir\Microsoft.Azure.Integration.DesignTools.Mapper.dll" /f
gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Integration SDK\IntegrationProjectExtnDir\Microsoft.Azure.Integration.DesignTools.TOM.dll" /f
gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Integration SDK\IntegrationProjectExtnDir\Microsoft.Azure.Integration.DesignTools.BaseFunctoids.dll" /f
```